# Create a new user in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, password, users

I tried to create a new user in 12.04 using the "Users menu", but although the user `guest` has been created, I never got asked a password. So when I logout and try to login as `guest`, I get asked a password which I don't know. How can I solve this?

Simply hitting `Enter` when asked for the password won't be accepted as a valid password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to "user account" again, select the newly created user and and under login options, next to password, click on "account disabled" to setup a password.

Comment: Excellent, I didn't see that the menu was clickable.

Comment: indeed, what a horrible GUI !