# Password problem after creating a new user 

Tags: password, users

I created a new user account and when I try to login to that account by switching accounts it said wrong password. I searched here and found my answer here - [Create a new user in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132186/create-a-new-user-in-12-04)

Now when I clicked enable this account and I don't know what happened from then.. now I'm with a problem that ubuntu don't recognising my password. It's saying there's no password set but when I'm clicking it it's asking for old password.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you leave the current password field blank?

Comment: Nothing. That 'Change' button still faded or inactive.

Comment: I guess [dropping to a root shell](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/09/recover-lost-passwords-in-ubuntu-12-04-recovery-mode/) would be overkill..

Comment: @SirCharlo that's what I was going to suggest, too.

Comment: Can't you just `sudo passwd <user>`? Just asking.

Comment: Okay i'll try this. @SirCharlo

Comment: @NlightNFotis That then saying - myusername@my.comp.name:~$ sudo passwd <user>
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
myusername@my.comp.name:~$

Comment: I'm going to try that 'dropping to a root shell'. I hope that'll work or I'll have no option but to install windows.

Comment: Man, it doesn't asked for password. I restarted but coz another user was logged in (I'm guessing) ubuntu took me to login screen. There was just 'log-in' to press and no field to enter password. But when I've to change setting in user accounts it's asking for password. However I'm administrator.

Comment: @rainlover while trying to do what @NlightNFotis said, you need to replace `<user>` with YOUR username. Do not keep the `<` and `>` symbols. And finally if your username contains special characters (Not sure if this is possible, never tried it), then you have to put quotes around your username. For example: `sudo passwd "dan"`

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest taking NlightNFotis' advice: open a terminal and type

```
sudo passwd <user>
```

Comment: Yeah, this way you are super user(root) authorized to change <user>'s password to your liking. There is a problem however if you are not in the sudoer's group and have no account with access to sudo commands.

Comment: I would upvote this, but for some strange kind of fashion, I have reached my daily upvoting limit.