# How to add a new user in Ubuntu 12.04, and how i give them a root user privileges

Tags: users

> How to add a new user in Ubuntu 12.04, and how i give them a root user
>   privileges

Comment: Server or desktop? And this will have been asked before ... See... http://askubuntu.com/questions/132186/create-a-new-user-in-12-04?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 12.04 and later

If the user already exists

```
sudo  usermod -aG sudo <username>
```

To create the user

```
adduser <username> --group sudo
```

replace username with the name of the user and remove < >